# Number with thousand decimal and two digit after comma

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I  need thousand decimal and two digit after comma like following picture.

[image]

https://brutmaas.net/maas-hesaplama/brutten-nete/tablo

Following code need to be improved.

```
<input type="number" id="myInput" value="3512.12" 
onfocus="focusFunction()" 
onblur="blurFunction()" style="text-align: right" />
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: you need to do this with `css`. i think the easiest way is to use two different HTML elements: `<p class="before">233.585</p><p class="after">72</p>`

Comment: Are you asking about the punctuation or the sup of the ,12?

Comment: That page uses the following HTML `<span class="numeric">152<sup>,21</sup></span>`

Comment: @MarkoMarkowitz Don't you just need another `<input />` to hold the two digits after a comma?

Comment: @MarkoMarkowitz Ah, you mean you want to format a number with a comma for the thousandth separator? And you want that as a single `<input type="number" />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little snippet that does basically the same thing as the example page you gave:

```js
// Factory to produce a new number container based on the input value
function createNumericDisplay(input){
  var display = document.createElement("div"), decimal = document.createElement("sup"), number = new Number(input.value).toLocaleString('de-DE').split(",");
  if(number.length == 1){
    number[1] = "0";
  }
  display.setAttribute("class", "numeric");
  display.innerText = number[0];
  decimal.innerText = ","+number[1].lpad("0",2).substr(0,2);
  display.appendChild(decimal);
  return display;
}

// Creates or removes the number
function toggleNumericDisplay(input, show){
  var display = input.parentNode.querySelector(".numeric");
  if(display && !show){
    display.parentNode.removeChild(display);
  }else if(!display && show){
    display = createNumericDisplay(input);
    input.parentNode.appendChild(display);
  }
}

// When we focus, remove the formatted number container
function focusFunction(ev) {
    toggleNumericDisplay(ev.target, false);
}
// When we blur, create the formatted number container
function blurFunction(ev) {
    toggleNumericDisplay(ev.target, true);
}

// Pad a string with zeroes
String.prototype.lpad = function(padString, length) {
    var str = this;
    while (str.length < length)
        str = padString + str;
    return str;
}

// Initialize values
var numerics = document.body.querySelectorAll(".numeric-wrapper input");
for(var i=0; i<numerics.length; ++i){
  toggleNumericDisplay(numerics[i], true);
}
```

```css
.numeric-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font: 13.3333px "Arial" !important;
  
}
.numeric-wrapper .numeric {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
}
.numeric-wrapper .numeric sup {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<div class="numeric-wrapper">
   <input type="number" id="myInput" value="1450.91" onfocus="focusFunction(event)" onblur="blurFunction(event)" style="text-align: right" step="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot click it because the function is not defined yet due to the structure of the fiddle. I've updated your fiddle to attach the event listeners dynamically on load: https://jsfiddle.net/owbx8fnk/3/

Comment: I've added a snippet to the blurFunction which truncates the number to 2 decimal places: https://jsfiddle.net/owbx8fnk/4/

Comment: @MarkoMarkowitz I don't have time to build your entire app for you, good luck with further developments.

Comment: I need your support to solve IE and Firefox errors which you can see in linked picture https://prnt.sc/i656hk

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [pattern attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) to restrict which characters can be entered (the following restricts to digits, dots and commas):

```html
<input type="text" id="num" name="number"
       pattern="[0-9.,]+"
       onkeypress="return window.validate && validate(event);"
       title="Enter german localized number" />
```

Then some JavaScript to validate the format upon the keypress event either manually or using [globalize.numberParser( [options] )](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#user-content-numberparser-options-).

```js
function validate(e) {
    var valid = true;

    var text = document.getElementById("num").value;

    // either manually check if format is valid e.g.
    var firstLetter = text.charAt(0);
    if(firstLetter === ".") {
        valid = false;
    }

    // etc.

    // or parse/validate with globalize
    var num = Globalize.numberParser(/*german locale*/)("10.000,00")
    valid = !isNaN(parseFloat(num)) && isFinite(num);

    return valid;
}
```

Another option could be to let someone enter `1234.56` (or whatever their local equivalent is) then format that into 1.234,56?

Comment: 1- The number must be inculuded thousand decimal. 2- The number must be inculuded ony two digits after comma. 3- Letter is not allowed.

Comment: @MarkoMarkowitz I updated the example with [globalize.numberParser](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#user-content-numberparser-options-)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: @MarkoMarkowitz That's the link I already have in the answer ;o)